# Navbar bootstrap esconde itens, mas não mostra quando clicado

Tags: css, bootstrap

O agrupamento funciona quando diminuo a janela, ele coloca todos os itens do menu escondido e mostra o botão com três "-", porém quando clico no botão ele não mostra os menus que fora escondidos, ele só reaparecem se eu aumentar a tela novamente para um tamanho que as caibam.

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" class="container">
    <div>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#minhaNavbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="minhaNavbar">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>

                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Meu menu</a>
                </div>

                <div id="minhaNavbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#agenda">Teste 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#consulta">Teste 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#sair">Sair</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                </div>

            </div>
        </nav>

        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Eu mesmo resolvi o problema sem querer. O problema é que eu estou usando uma master page e nas páginas agregadas a master page eu não coloquei esta linha:
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" /> 

Após colocar esta linha nas outras páginas está funcionando tudo normalmente.

Comment: responda sua própria pergunta, ou apague ela.

Answer (score 2):

Eu mesmo resolvi o problema sem querer. O problema é que eu estou usando uma master page e nas páginas agregadas a master page eu não coloquei esta linha:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```

Após colocar esta linha nas outras páginas está funcionando tudo normalmente.

Comment: Muito obrigado!